# Is there a way to rollback failed bulk insert in sql if I can't touch the insert query? triggers maybe?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a MySQL Database that receives bulk inserts that are sent from another db owned by a different team that I can't tell what to do, so I can't change their insert query. The thing is some times not all the entries from the bulk insert end up in my database. So I was thinking to put a trigger to make a save point, and another trigger to rollback the insert if it fails. but the thing is how could I tell if the insert failed with SQL code? does anybody have any idea?